# Not able to show committers list in Jenkins Jelly email template

Tags: jenkins, findbugs, jelly

We have recently migrated our jenkins to 1.6 version and I have findbug project set. While showing findbug results in email using below jelly template, "Find Bugs warnings info" section shows error message as "Find Bugs Publisher did not get invoked due to an error". But I do not see any error in console.

Also, "New Warnings" section is not showing up. It looks that  fb variable is null and no results are showing up in email template.

Even the change sets section is not visible.

Is there any setting missing for findbug in Jenkins required to show up these results.

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>${project.name}</title>
            <style>
                body table, td, th, p, h1, h2 {
                    margin:0;
                    font:normal normal
                    90% Georgia, Serif;
                    background-color: #ffffff;
                }
                h1, h2 {
                    border-bottom:dotted 1px #999999;
                    padding:5px;
                    margin-top:10px;
                    margin-bottom:10px;
                    color: #000000;
                    font: normal bold 90%
                    Georgia,Serif;
                    background-color:#f0f0f0;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="header">
                <j:set var="spc" value="&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;" />
                <h1>
                    <j:choose>
                        <j:when test="${build.result=='SUCCESS'}">
                            <img src="${rooturl}static/e59dfe28/images/32x32/blue.gif" />
                        </j:when>
                        <j:when test="${build.result=='FAILURE'}">
                            <img src="${rooturl}static/e59dfe28/images/32x32/red.gif" />
                        </j:when>
                        <j:otherwise>
                            <img
                src="${rooturl}static/e59dfe28/images/32x32/yellow.gif" />
                        </j:otherwise>
                    </j:choose>
                    BUILD ${build.result}
                </h1>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Build URL</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="${rooturl}${build.url}">${rooturl}${build.url}</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Project:</td>
                        <td>${project.name}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Date of build:</td>
                        <td>${it.timestampString}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Build duration:</td>
                        <td>${build.durationString}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Build cause:</td>
                        <td>
                            <j:forEach var="cause" items="${build.causes}">${cause.shortDescription}
                            </j:forEach>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Build description:</td>
                        <td>${build.description}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Built on:</td>
                        <td>
                            <j:choose>
                                <j:when test="${build.builtOnStr!=''}">${build.builtOnStr} 
                                </j:when>
                                <j:otherwise>master</j:otherwise>
                            </j:choose>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- Static Analysis -->
            <j:set var="actions" value="${it.staticAnalysisActions}" />
            <j:if test="${!actions.isEmpty()}">
                <div class="content">
                    <h1>Static Analysis Results</h1>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Result</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                <th>High</th>
                                <th>Normal</th>
                                <th>Low</th>
                            </tr>
                            <j:forEach var="action" items="${actions}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <img src="${rooturl}${action.smallImageName}" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="${rooturl}${build.url}/${action.urlName}">${action.displayName}
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="center">
                                        <j:choose>
                                            <j:when test="${action.result.pluginResult=='SUCCESS'}">
                                                <img src="${rooturl}static/e59dfe28/images/16x16/blue.gif" />
                                            </j:when>
                                            <j:when test="${action.result.pluginResult=='FAILURE'}">
                                                <img src="${rooturl}static/e59dfe28/images/16x16/red.gif" />
                                            </j:when>
                                            <j:otherwise>
                                                <img src="${rooturl}static/e59dfe28/images/16x16/yellow.gif" />
                                            </j:otherwise>
                                        </j:choose>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="center">${action.result.numberOfAnnotations} 
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="center">${action.result.getNumberOfAnnotations('HIGH')} 
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="center">${action.result.getNumberOfAnnotations('NORMAL')} 
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="center">${action.result.getNumberOfAnnotations('LOW')} 
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </j:forEach>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </j:if>
                <!-- More Find bugs info-->
<j:set var="fb" value="${it.getAction('hudson.plugins.findbugs.FindBugsResultAction')}" />
<div class="content">
    <h1>Find Bugs warnings info</h1>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Fixed</th>
            <th>New</th>
            <th >Report</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="center">${fb.result.numberOfWarnings}</td>
            <td class="center">${fb.result.numberOfFixedWarnings}</td>
            <td class="center">${fb.result.numberOfNewWarnings}</td>
            <td class="center"><a href="${rooturl}${build.url}/findbugsResult">View Report</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<j:set var="newWarnings" value="${fb.result.newWarnings}" />
<j:if test="${newWarnings!=null}">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>New warnings</h1>
        <table width="100%" class="newWarningsborder">
            <tr>
                <th width="20%" class="newWarningsborder">Name</th>
                <th width="5%" class="newWarningsborder">Line</th>
                <th width="*" class="newWarningsborder">Message</th>
            </tr>
            <j:forEach var="fileAnnotation" items="${newWarnings}" varStatus="loop">
                <tr>
                    <td width="20%" class="newWarningsborder">${fileAnnotation.shortFileName}</td>
                    <td width="5%" class="newWarningsborder">${fileAnnotation.primaryLineNumber}</td>
                    <td width="*" class="newWarningsborder">${fileAnnotation.message}</td>
                </tr>
            </j:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>
</j:if>
<!-- CHANGE SET -->
<div class="content">
    <j:set var="changeSet" value="${build.changeSet}" />
    <j:if test="${changeSet!=null}">
        <j:set var="hadChanges" value="false" />
        <a href="${rooturl}${build.url}/changes">
            <h1>Changes</h1>
        </a>
        <j:forEach var="cs" items="${changeSet.logs}" varStatus="loop">
            <j:set var="hadChanges" value="true" />
            <h2>${cs.msgAnnotated}</h2>
            <p>
                by
                <em>${cs.author}</em>
            </p>
            <table>
            <j:forEach var="p" items="${cs.affectedFiles}">
                <tr>
                    <td width="10%">${spc}${p.editType.name}</td>
                    <td>
                    <tt>${p.path}</tt>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </j:forEach>
        </table>
    </j:forEach>
    <j:if test="${!hadChanges}">
        <p>No Changes</p>
    </j:if>
    <br />
    </j:if>
</div>
<!-- ARTIFACTS -->
<j:set var="artifacts" value="${build.artifacts}" />
<j:if test="${artifacts!=null and artifacts.size()&gt;0}">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Build Artifacts</h1>
        <ul>
            <j:forEach var="f" items="${artifacts}">
                <li>
                    <a href="${rooturl}${build.url}artifact/${f}">${f}</a>
                </li>
            </j:forEach>
        </ul>
    </div>
</j:if>
<!-- MAVEN ARTIFACTS -->
<j:set var="mbuilds" value="${build.moduleBuilds}" />
<j:if test="${mbuilds!=null}">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Build Artifacts</h1>
        <j:forEach var="m" items="${mbuilds}">
            <h2>${m.key.displayName}</h2>
            <j:forEach var="mvnbld" items="${m.value}">
                <j:set var="artifacts" value="${mvnbld.artifacts}" />
                <j:if test="${artifacts!=null and artifacts.size()&gt;0}">
                    <ul>
                        <j:forEach var="f" items="${artifacts}">
                            <li>
                                <a href="${rooturl}${mvnbld.url}artifact/${f}">${f}</a>
                            </li>
                        </j:forEach>
                    </ul>
                </j:if>
            </j:forEach>
        </j:forEach>
        <br />
    </div>
</j:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you run FindBugs during the job? Is it a maven project?

Comment: Yes, it is a maven project and I do run FindBugs. Also, when I try to take a build and try to generate email for that build using Email Template Testing feature, still I do not see the committers list in my generated email.

Comment: Then you should find something like [FINDBUGS] in the log, can you look for it?

Comment: I did check loggers but there is not error that I can relate to error with email. However, once the email is generated, I get "Find Bugs Publisher did not get invoked due to an error. For further information, click here. " When I click for more info, I see below logs

[WARNINGS] Skipping publisher since build result is FAILURE
[ANALYSIS-COLLECTOR] Computing warning deltas based on reference build #xyz
Email was triggered for: Failure - Any
Sending email for trigger: Failure - Any
Sending email to: testaccount@gmail.com
Finished: FAILURE